# Авторизация на сайте с использованием csrfmiddlewaretoken

Tags: c#, http, token, httpwebrequest

Мне необходимо авторизоваться на сайте, и дальше работать с POST запросами, но есть проблема на сайте выдается csrfmiddlewaretoken.
Поэтому надо сначала зайди на сайт, методом GET взять csrfmiddlewaretoken типа "7e9001a3c0000f11099c11h119745e30" и затей его использовать при логине в методе POST, сохранить куки после логина и работать дальше. Проблема в том что csrfmiddlewaretoken каждый раз меняется.
Параметры которые отправляются при логине

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken "7e9001a3c0000f11099c11h119745e30"
username    "логин"
password    "пароль"
next    "/about/"
```

Побывал так

```
WebResponse Response;
HttpWebRequest Request;
Uri url = new Uri("http://00.00.00.000:0000/accounts/login/");
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
Request.Method = "GET";
Request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
Response = Request.GetResponse(); //1 раз получил csrfmiddlewaretoken

string Parametros = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + cookieContainer.GetCookies(url)["csrftoken"].Value + "&username=логин&password=пароль&next=/about/";

Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
//вот тут получается мне выдадут потом новый токен, а без использования этого я не знаю как сформировать новый запрос
Request.Method = "POST";
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
Request.Headers.Add("Cookie", Response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie"));
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Parametros);
Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Response = Request.GetResponse();
```

На сайте он выглядит так:

```
<form method="POST" action="/accounts/login/" class="well" autocomplete="off"> <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="7e9001a3c2801f25097c11e119745e31" /></div>
```

---

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://00.00.00.000:0000/accounts/login/");

CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

string Parametros = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + cookieContainer.GetCookies(url)["csrftoken"].Value + "&username=логин&password=пароль&next=/about/";
Console.WriteLine(Parametros);
//Paremetros "csrfmiddlewaretoken=d113dc9681a9ed800397f6164b608114&username=логин&password=пароль&next=/about/"

httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = Parametros.Length;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
//httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", httpWebRequest.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie"));

using (Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
  byte[] paramAsBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Parametros);
  stream.Write(paramAsBytes, 0, paramAsBytes.Count());
}
httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
//тут получаю Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (401) Несанкционированный
```

А если

```
 //httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
 httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie",httpWebRequest.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie"));
```

То получаю
    "Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (403) Запрещено."

Comment: Вы что-то упустили. Возможно вам нужно почитать про авторизацию и аутентификацию в IIS.

Comment: Я в сишарпах мало понимаю, но ставить в запросе вместе cookieContainer и заголовок Cookie точно можно?

Comment: Я это добавил т.к. не понимаю, достаточно ли 1ого Request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer; Ну даже если я удалю эту строчку ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

Удалил из строки &next=/about/

```
string Parametros = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + cookieContainer.GetCookies(url)["csrftoken"].Value + "&username=логин&password=пароль&next=/about/";

string Parametros = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + cookieContainer.GetCookies(url)["csrftoken"].Value + "&username=логин&password=пароль";
```

И заработало, хотя в браузере она передается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]